# Rails - Failed to build native extensions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, macos

I'm currently trying to embark on my first rails project and when I try to run the command `rails new file_name` I eventually get the error `ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

I am currently using rvm to run ruby 2.2 on my mac osx 10.8.5. Everytime I run rails it seems to fail at the json gem.

`Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

I am lost as to what is going on. If I try to run install json I also get a failed to build native extension error. Could it be my versions of xcode command line tools because when I try to run xcode-select --install it says command doesn't exist? I don't know. Any help would be appreciated.

edit as per Leonardo's request:
`Installing json 1.8.3 with native extensions`

`Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.`

```
/Users/davidgarczynski/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150817-32366-1n36tmw.rb extconf.rb
```

`creating Makefile`

`make "DESTDIR=" clean`

`make "DESTDIR="`
`compiling generator.c`
`make: I.: No such file or directory`
`make: [generator.o] Error 1 (ignored)`
`linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle`
`make: dynamic: No such file or directory`
`make: [generator.bundle] Error 1 (ignored)`

`make "DESTDIR=" install`
`compiling generator.c`
`make: I.: No such file or directory`
`make: [generator.o] Error 1 (ignored)`
`linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle`
`make: dynamic: No such file or directory`
`make: [generator.bundle] Error 1 (ignored)`
`/usr/bin/install -m 0755 generator.bundle ./.gem.20150817-32366-b8ng6y/json/ext`
`install: generator.bundle: No such file or directory`
`make: *** [install-so] Error 71`

`make install failed, exit code 2`

`Gem files will remain installed in /Users/davidgarczynski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/json-1.8.3 for inspection.`
`Results logged to /Users/davidgarczynski/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/json-1.8.3/gem_make.out`
`An error occurred while installing json (1.8.3), and Bundler cannot continue.`
`Make sure that`gem install json -v '1.8.3'`succeeds before bundling.`

Comment: Could you post the entire log error? The error you are giving us is quite generic

Comment: Before stack overflow was giving me an error when I tried to submit code saying it wasn't formatted properly. I don't know why it went through now. Possibly because I backticked every line this time, but take a look at that.

Comment: Have you opened Xcode and installed the command line tools? Also you might just have to start up Xcode once to get past a dialogue box concerning the command line tools.

Comment: I have. Even tried uninstalling and reinstalling xcode at a certain point. I've read I should try to type xcode-select --install into terminal but i get an error with that as well. Unknown command. Currently I am just updating my entire system to Mavericks. We'll see what happens (edit: in 5 hours...)

Comment: Have you tried installing a ruby-dev version from your ruby version manager and trying again?

Comment: If that doesn't work, try to execute in console the command: gem install json -v '1.8.3'